# Python: using only certain keys in a dictionary for a for-loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, key

Another python-dictionary question :)

here's my dictionary:

```
mydict = {key1: valueA, key2: valueA, key3: valueB, key4: valueA,
key5: valueA, key6: valueB, key7: valueB, key8: valueA, key9: valueB}
```

now i want to iterate through the dictionary only for the key-value-pairs of
`key4`, `key5`, `key6` and `key7` and check if the value is `valueB`. 
i hope it is possible to understand what i mean..

i want to create a for-loop, and only if the value of key4 is valueB, the content of the loop should be executed, then, if the value of key5 is valueB, it should be executed again, and so on. thanks in advance

Comment: You can iterate over `["key4","key5","key6","key7"]`?

Comment: It isn't clear, to me, what you mean. Please, try to explain better with a concrete example. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
for key in [key4, key5, key6, key7]:
    if mydict[key] == valueB:
        pass # do stuff here
```

Answer (score 6):

"from `key4` to `key7`" is **not a meaningful concept**. A dictionary is fundamentally **unordered**. There is no sensible way to say that one key comes before or after another.

Determine all the keys you want to check, and check them.

Comment: i know that it's unordered, maybe i should write key4, key5, key6, key7 to be clearer

Comment: The other answers are perfect, in that case. Although honestly I don't know how you got to this point without being able to reason out something similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
for key in ["key4","key5","key6","key7"]:
   if mydict[key] == valueB :
      #do what you want
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a set of `ignored_keys` and then just remove those keys before iteration.

```
for key in mydicts.keys() - ignore_keys:
    value = mydict[key]
    ....
```

Comment: This is a much better answer, as it is more generally useful and will yield a more scalable coding pattern.